# javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException while inserting new Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Building an Application for handling punishments in soccer etc. Like too late for training and so on.

First of all: It's a Spring Boot App with Vaadin Frontend and an H2 Database with Spring Data JPA

The Problem ist by adding new Entities to the H2 Database. Inserting Players and Punishments on itself is no Problem, but when I'm trying to map those Ids with another table (PunishmentToPlayer), it gives me an EntityNotFoundException.

The Player and Punishment Entities are also correct in the Database.

Entity Player

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Player extends AbstractEntity{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Entity Punishment

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Punishment extends AbstractEntity{

    private String description;
    private Double amount;
}
```

Entity PunishmentToPlayer

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class PunishmentToPlayer extends AbstractEntity{

    @OneToOne
    private Player player;

    @OneToOne
    private Punishment punishment;
}
```

Trying to add my sample Data here

```
@Component
public class DataHelper {

    public void addPlayer(PlayerService playerService){
        playerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPlayer("Player1_Name", "Player1_Lastname"));
        playerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPlayer("Player2_Name", "Player2_Lastname"));
        playerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPlayer("Player3_Name", "Player3_Lastname"));
        playerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPlayer("Player4_Name", "Player4_Lastname"));
    }

    public void addPunishments(PunishmentService punishmentService){
        punishmentService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishment("Description 1", 20.00));
        punishmentService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishment("Description 2", 15.00));
        punishmentService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishment("Description 3", 10.00));
        punishmentService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishment("Description 4", 5.00));
    }

    public void addConnections(PunishmentToPlayerService punishmentToPlayerService, PlayerService playerService, PunishmentService punishmentService){
        List<Player> players =  playerService.getAllPlayer();
        List<Punishment> punishments = punishmentService.getAllPunishments();

        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(0), punishments.get(0)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(0), punishments.get(2)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(1), punishments.get(1)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(2), punishments.get(0)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(2), punishments.get(3)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(3), punishments.get(0)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(3), punishments.get(3)));
        punishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(buildPunishmentToPlayer(players.get(3), punishments.get(3)));
    }

    private Player buildPlayer(String firstname, String lastname){
        return Player.builder()
                .firstName(firstname)
                .lastName(lastname)
                .build();
    }

    private Punishment buildPunishment(String description, double value){
        return Punishment.builder()
                .description(description)
                .amount(value)
                .build();
    }

    private PunishmentToPlayer buildPunishmentToPlayer(Player player, Punishment punishment){
        return PunishmentToPlayer.builder()
                .player(player)
                .punishment(punishment)
                .build();
    }
}
```

When Debugging it shows me all the correct Data in the single PunishmentToPlayerObjects
[image]

In the saveOrUpdate Method from DataHelper the PunishmentToPlayerService calls Method:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(PunishmentToPlayer punishmentToPlayer){
        punishmentToPlayerRepository.save(punishmentToPlayer);
}
```

Which only refers to the standard `save` method of the CrudRepository from Spring Data

Here the Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find de.nils.Tus_Strafen.model.Player with id a62dde9d-2514-44d8-9d97-7d54afd69ef8; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find de.nils.Tus_Strafen.model.Player with id a62dde9d-2514-44d8-9d97-7d54afd69ef8
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:379) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at de.nils.Tus_Strafen.service.PunishmentToPlayerService.saveOrUpdate(PunishmentToPlayerService.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.nils.Tus_Strafen.DataHelper.addConnections(DataHelper.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.nils.Tus_Strafen.view.views.MainAppLayout.addData(MainAppLayout.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.nils.Tus_Strafen.view.views.MainAppLayout.<init>(MainAppLayout.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
```

Didn't really try anything special, because it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding cascade type all for `player` and `punishment` field in `PunishmentToPlayer` class

```
public class PunishmentToPlayer extends AbstractEntity{

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Player player;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Punishment punishment;
}
```

Comment: Its kind of an success due to another Exception now:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Eindeutiger Index oder Primärschlüssel verletzt: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.PLAYER(ID) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(X'3ca0c9cdc2164e32a6b67e454b2eb8ad0' AS BINARY(255)) )"
Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.PLAYER(ID) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(X'3ca0c9cdc2164e32a6b67e454b2eb8ad0' AS BINARY(255)) )"; SQL statement:
insert into player (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]`

Comment: Seems there is unique constraint issue due existing data in your database. try truncating concerned tables or empty whole database and retry

Comment: The Database starts local with my Application. The Data is also added then.

Comment: Does AbstractEntity entity class has auto generate Id ?

Comment: No but this:
`protected AbstractEntity() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }`

Comment: I would recommand hibernate for that: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id. This link could be useful https://www.baeldung.com/java-hibernate-uuid-primary-key.

Comment: With GenerationType. I can only use AUTO, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE, TABLE

Comment: seems you have a version less than 6.2 for hibernate. Some way you can try: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;